# Как вывести значение массива из класса в Java?

Tags: java

Нужна помощь. Как вывести значение массива? Массив я создал с помощью методов. В консоль должен отображаться значения, а не адрес к значениям. Как исправить ошибку? Вот код.

```
class Author {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private char gender;

    Author(String name, String email, char gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    Author(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class Book {
    private String name;
    private Author[] authors = new Author[5];
    private int numAuthors = 0;
    private double price;
    private int qtyInStock = 0;

    Book (String valueName, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    } 

    Book (String name, double price, int qtyInStock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;   
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

/*  public Author getAuthors() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numAuthors; i++)
            return authors[i];
    } 
*/
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQtyInStock() {
        return qtyInStock;
    }

    public void setQtyInStock(int qtyInStock) {
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "\n" + price + "\n" + qtyInStock;
    }

    public void printAuthors() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numAuthors; i++)
            System.out.println(((i + 1) + ". " + this.authors[i]));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void addAuthor(Author author) {
        this.authors[numAuthors] = author;
        ++numAuthors;
    }  


    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Book gameOfThrones = new Book("Game of Thrones", 27.45, 873);
        System.out.println(gameOfThrones);
        gameOfThrones.addAuthor(new Author("Leskhan Iskender"));
        gameOfThrones.addAuthor(new Author("Iskander Manas"));
        System.out.println("The authors are: ");
        gameOfThrones.printAuthors();

        

        Book javaDummy = new Book("Java for Dummy", 19.99, 99);
        System.out.println(javaDummy);  // toString()
        System.out.println("The authors are: ");
        javaDummy.printAuthors();
        
        javaDummy.addAuthor(new Author("Tan Ah Teck", "AhTeck@somewhere.com", 'm'));
        javaDummy.addAuthor(new Author("Paul Tan", "Paul@nowhere.com", 'm'));
        System.out.println(javaDummy);  // toString()
        System.out.println("The authors are: ");
        javaDummy.printAuthors();
    }
}
```

Вот результат:

[image: Ответ]

Вместо **Author@41629346**

должен быть **Leskhan Iskender**

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Author {
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```